# How to "Stop Flutter from rebuilding widgets" after app is closed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, weather

So I built my first app. It's a weather app. So far everything works as intended. But there is one problem, whenever I close the app and then reopen it, everything is null (weather forecast, location name, max and min temperature). When I press the refresh button it null is updated to current condition. What I'd like t be able to do is, instead of showing null, I'd like the app to show the last refresh and update it if I press the refresh button. How can I do this.

Keep in mind I'm a newbie.

**main.dart:**

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'GetLocation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AuraWeather());
}

class AuraWeather extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuraWeatherState createState() => _AuraWeatherState();
}

class _AuraWeatherState extends State<AuraWeather> {

  var apiKey = '5f10958d807d5c7e333ec2e54c4a5b16';
  var description;
  var city;
  var maxTemp;
  var minTemp;
  var temp;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      getLocation();
    });

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(displayBackground()),
          ),
        ),
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 2, sigmaX: 2),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
            child: Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            '$city',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 35,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.locationArrow,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 80),
                        child: Text(
                          '$temp' + '°',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 50,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.wb_sunny,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        '$maxTemp ° | $minTemp °',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Text(
                      '$description',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.refresh,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            getLocation();
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // display background images based on current time
  displayBackground() {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    final currentTime = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
    if (currentTime.contains('AM')) {
      return 'images/Blood.png';
    } else if (currentTime.contains('PM')) {
      return 'images/Sun.png';
    }
  }

  //getLocation
  void getLocation() async {
    Getlocation getlocation = Getlocation();
    await getlocation.getCurrentLocation();

    print(getlocation.latitude);
    print(getlocation.longitude);
    print(getlocation.city);
    city = getlocation.city;
    getTemp(getlocation.latitude, getlocation.longitude);
  }

  //Get current temp
  Future<void> getTemp(double lat, double lon) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');
    //print(response.body);

    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    description = dataDecoded['weather'][0]['description'];

    temp = dataDecoded['main']['temp'];
    temp = temp.toInt();

    maxTemp = dataDecoded['main']['temp_max'];
    maxTemp = maxTemp.toInt();

    minTemp = dataDecoded['main']['temp_min'];
    minTemp = minTemp.toInt();

    print(temp);
  }
}
```

**GetLocation.dart:**

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Getlocation {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    var city;
    //Get current location
    Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
        try {
            Position position = await Geolocator()
                    .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
            latitude = position.latitude;
            longitude = position.longitude;

            city = await getCityName(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        } catch (e) {
            print(e);
        }
    }

    //Get city name
    Future<String> getCityName(double lat, double lon) async {
        List<Placemark> placemark =
        await Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, lon);
        print('city name is: ${placemark[0].locality}');
        return placemark[0].locality;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution, would be to use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), then after you refresh weather save every variable to it, like

```
Future<void> _saveStringInSharedPrefs(String key, String value) async =>
  SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) => prefs.setString(key, value));
```

for each of the values. You may also want to change vars to types, like double, String and so on.

Then you can add initState to your state, where you set each of the variables to `SharedPreferences.getString(variable_key)`. It will be convenient to use `SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance()` and then call `prefs.getString()` You could add it in build, but you probably should not, build methods are meant to be really fast, so they could run up to 60 times/s.

Edit:

```
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');
    //print(response.body);

    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {prefs.setString('weather_data', response.body}) // add this line

    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    // (rest of the code)
```

This will save your json to SharedPrefs. Now you only need to extract the function that works with JSON and sets the variables. So it would look something like this:

```
void _setData(String jsonString) {
    var dataDecoded = jsonDecode(response.body);
    description = dataDecoded['weather'][0]['description'];

    // here it would be safer to have temp be of type 'int' instead of 'var' and set it like this:
    // temp = dataDecoded['main']['temp'].toInt();

    temp = dataDecoded['main']['temp'];
    temp = temp.toInt();

    maxTemp = dataDecoded['main']['temp_max'];
    maxTemp = maxTemp.toInt();

    minTemp = dataDecoded['main']['temp_min'];
    minTemp = minTemp.toInt();
}
```

You can then split getTemp like that:

```
  Future<void> getTemp(double lat, double lon) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric');
    //print(response.body);

    _setData(response.body);
  }
```

And then, when you launch the app you want it to load the values from SharedPreferences. So add this to _AuraWeatherState:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
}

Future<void> _loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _setData(prefs.getString('weather_data'));
}
```

This should work but I didn't have time to check if it executes. So if you have any other questions, I'll be glad to help :)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Could you show me how to implement it on my code?

Comment: I'll get back to you after work, around 5 hours from now.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I have finished it, please try whether it works

Comment: is the a problem with this line of code:     await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {prefs.setString('weather_data', response.body});

Comment: Could you provide an error? Or try this: 
var prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('weather_data', response.body.toString());

Comment: `Future<void> getTemp(double lat, double lon) async {
    
     http.Response response = await http.get(
    'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$lon&appid=$apiKey&units=metric'); //print(response.body);

         var prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance(); prefs.setString('weather_data',response.body.toString());

        _setData(response.body);

  }`


Method **_setString_** isn't defined for the type **_Future_**. Plus, at the top where you added and @override, it says, expected a closing parenthesis. But I can't seen to figure out where it is needed.

Comment: I see, it should be var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(). You can extract the value of future by await, so for example: you have Future<int> that means that the value will be int in some time, so you can wait for it with await, then its type will be int. Also there was an extra parentheses int getTemp rewrite, maybe that was the issue? Are you using Android Studio maybe? It should mark that parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and sorry for the late feedback. Just finished my online final exams.  `_AuraWeatherState createState() => _AuraWeatherState(

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadData();
  }

  Future<void> _loadData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _setData(prefs.getString('weather_data'));
  }

  );`
The @override expects a closing parenthesis. I have checked and all are there. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: It's weird, try commenting out code until it compiles maybe, it's not a great habit but it should work :)